# QML Listview missing output

Tags: listview, qml

I want to output a list of users on a login page. For this I have created an userlistmodel based on QAbstractListModel and fill that with two users. So far everything works, on the qml page I get the output that 2 elements are in the listview.

I have assigned the model to the listview and set a small component as delegate.

logon.qml

```
Rectangle {
        id: userlist
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        Layout.preferredHeight: 300
        Layout.preferredWidth: 560  
        color: "white"
        RowLayout
        {
            ListItem { text1: "Benutzeranmeldung"; text2: "[1/2]"; icon: "key" }
    
            ListView {
                model: user.model
                clip: true
                delegate: ListItem { text1: name; text2: ""}
            }
        }
    }
```

ListItem.qml

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
import QtQuick.Layouts
import Exakt.Mills.System.ColorEnums 1.0

Item {
    id: item
    height: 30
    width: 400
    property string text1
    property string text2
    property string icon

    Rectangle {
        anchors.fill: parent
        Layout.fillWidth: true
        Layout.fillHeight: true
        color : "grey"
        RowLayout {
            Image {
                sourceSize.height: item.height * 0.8
                source: "image://iconprovider/user"
            }
            Label {
                text: text1
            }
            Label {
                text: text2
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately only the first (static) list entry is displayed, but the two users are not displayed. Alignment and formatting are still missing, it is first about the pure output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Neither your `RowLayout` nor your `ListView` have dimensions. The minimal fixes required are:

```
    RowLayout {
        anchors.fill: parent
        ListView {
            Layout.fillWidth: true
            Layout.fillHeight: true
        }
    }
```

Comment: Perfect thanks, with preferredHeight and preferredWidth it works now